# Can an iPad app directly launch another app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios4

I was wondering if it was possible to launch an iPad app directly from within another app.  For example, could I write a login page that takes you too a desktop type page where you can select an app to run, and then launch that app as say, a new thread?  I am not sure this is possible, I am just curious about the capabilities of the new iOS multitasking features.  Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It depends on the app you wish to launch. Some of them register URLs that let you launch links like itunes:// and the like. Check this out: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/StandardBehaviors/StandardBehaviors.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW7

The important section is the one entitled "Implementing Custom URL Schemes".

EDIT: Here's a link to a website that catalogs the various URLs for existing apps: http://handleopenurl.com/.

Comment: That actually sounds like it may work.  Thanks for the responses guys!

Answer (score 3):

Can you use custom url schemes to launch other apps

http://www.idev101.com/code/Objective-C/custom_url_schemes.html

Answer (score 2):

There's a directory of existing URL registrations at [HandleOpenURL](http://handleopenurl.com) that might come in handy here too.