# Action to open iMessage (Swift)

Tags: swift

I've been searching around and can't seem to find this one...

Is it possible to create an action within my app that opens iMessage and populates the To: field with a phone number? I think this is possible as Postmates has this feature... just not sure what methods to call.

Thanks!
Mark

Comment: You may be looking for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728854/is-it-possible-to-launch-another-app-in-ios-8-using-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `MFMessageComposeViewController`.

It doesn't "open iMessage" it creates an iMessage compose screen. You can repopulate the telephone number and even put a message.

The user can then edit the message and tap "Send" just like sending an iMessage.