# Open iMessage from my application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, imessage, ios-extensions

Is there any way to open iMessage apple app from my app? I don't need any composers, the main idea is to open actual iMessage with my extension.

EDITED

I don't want to send any messages; I need only iMessage App to be opened

Comment: "I don't need any composers", why not? I assume that [this answer should help you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31548887/action-to-open-imessage-swift)

Comment: because I need exactly iMessage to access my iMessage extension

Comment: Did you try `MFMessageComposeViewController` to open `iMessage`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

this can be done as follows (in Swift 2):

```
let phoneNumber = "958585858"
let text = "Some message"

guard let messageURL = NSURL(string: "sms:\(phoneNumber)&body=\(text)") 
else { return }
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(messageURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(messageURL)
}
```

and if you only need to open messages app :

```
guard let messageAppURL = NSURL(string: "sms:")
else { return }
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(messageAppURL) {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(messageAppURL)
}
```

make sure to add `sms:` to `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your `Info.plist`

Comment: how can we send group message to an array of recepients   using the above idea ?

Comment: For Swift 3, use the answer from @Rajat

Comment: @Hammad I want to open Messages application with a predefined message, but with no phone number provided . Is this how should I format my code?    `let message = "some invitation message"
            guard let messageAppURL = URL(string: "sms: &body=\(message)") else {return}`

Answer (score 6):

With swift3 you can do it like this

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string:"sms:")!) {
     UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string:"sms:")!, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Comment: This works well! I made an edit to only construct URL once.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what will open the Messages app without showing also showing the "send message" composer. I couldn't get the other solutions here to work without showing such a composer, so I figured I'd try to hack it another way:

```
if let url = URL(string: "messages://"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
}
```

Full disclosure: I have only tested this on iOS 14, and I have not tried submitting it to the App Store to see if Apple approves it or not.

Answer (score 0):

ViewController.h

```
NSString *app = @"Messages.app";
```

ViewController.m

```
// https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace?language=objc
- (IBAction)openclick:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Opening iMessage");
    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:(NSString *)app];
}
```