# Swift: How to open a new app when UIButton is tapped

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift

I have an app and when a uibutton is clicked, I want to open another app that is already installed (i.e. Waze). How can I do such? Big thanks.

Comment: I want to open Waze that is already installed in my phone

Comment: I think this is your answer. Hope it helps
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697105/5417484](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27697105/5417484)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try this. For example you want to open an Instagram app:

```
let instagramHooks = "instagram://user?username=johndoe"
let instagramUrl = URL(string: instagramHooks)!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(instagramUrl)
{  
    UIApplication.shared.open(instagramUrl)
} else {
    //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
    UIApplication.shared.open(URL(string: "http://instagram.com/")!)
}
```

Comment: That code is changed to this: UIApplication.shared.openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/")! as URL)

Comment: Are there a way to how to do this for other apps? I can not seem to make it work with Facebook...

Answer (score 8):

In SecondApp

Go to the plist file of SecondApp and you need to add a URL Schemes with a string iOSDevTips(of course you can write another string.it's up to you).

[image]

2 . In FirstApp

Create a button with the below action:

```
- (void)buttonPressed:(UIButton *)button
{
  NSString *customURL = @"iOSDevTips://";

  if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]])
  {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:customURL]];
  }
  else
  {
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"URL error"
                              message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No custom URL defined for %@", customURL]
                              delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                              otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
  }

}
```

That's it. Now when you can click the button in the FirstApp it should open the SecondApp.

For more info Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419119/launch-an-app-from-within-another-iphone)

Answer (score 4):

You can look up [Waze Community](https://www.waze.com/about/dev) for reference.

Objective-C code snippet:

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication]
canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"waze://"]]) {

  // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
  NSString *urlStr =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"waze://?ll=%f,%f&navigate=yes",
    latitude, longitude];

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];

 } else {

  // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL
    URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106"]];
}
```

Swift code snippet:

```
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "waze://")!) {
    // Waze is installed. Launch Waze and start navigation
    let urlStr = String(format: "waze://?ll=%f, %f&navigate=yes", latitude, longitude)
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: urlStr)!)
} else {
    // Waze is not installed. Launch AppStore to install Waze app
    UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id323229106")!)
}
```

Comment: Note that when compiling with iOS SDK 9.0 and up, you need to update your application's plist with the following code to include Waze.

    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>waze</string>
    </array>

Answer (score 3):

In Swift 4 you can use:

```
if let url = URL(string: "\(myUrl)") {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in swift4 waze

```
class FullMapVC: UIViewController {

    var lat:CLLocationDegrees?
    var long:CLLocationDegrees?

    func wazeMaps()
    {
        let openUrl = URL(string: "waze://?ll=\(String(describing: lat!)),\(String(describing: long!))&navigate=yes")!
        UIApplication.shared.open(openUrl , options:[:]) { (success) in
            if !success
            {

            }
        }
    }

}
```

replace url with if you wanna use google maps

```
 let openUrl = URL(string: "comgooglemaps://?saddr=&daddr=\(String(describing: lat!)),\(String(describing: long!))&directionsmode=driving")!
```

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 4 / 5 / ..., you can do it properly like this :

```
if let url = URL(string: url), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(url)
} else {
    // display error ?
}
```