# Using multiple storyboards all created in different projects and loading them from a menu system xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, storyboard

I am a new iOS developer. I have created 5 simple applications - all of which are very different and have no related files.

I now am faced with having 5 separate iOS apps. 
I wish to make a menu system and load each app from here...

Is this possible?

Comment: You mean something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33932303/swift-how-to-open-a-new-app-when-uibutton-is-tapped?

Comment: Unfortunately these are all apps I have created myself, therefore have no URL's.. really stuck!

Comment: Then I would try to register those urls using  deep linking. I haven't tried it myself, but following [link](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-deep-linking-in-swift/) seems to give some explanation as how to do that.

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately Apple no longer support URL schemes for deep linking, will keep searching!

Comment: also, this is for my final year project.. so i have a developer account but not releasing the app to the app store,so dont have app store ID's

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically, it should be possible. I have not tested this out myself and so take this with a grain of salt :) You might have to remove the "Is Initial View Controller" setting from the five storyboards so that none of the initial view controllers load - I am not quite sure if this would be needed or not, but might be worth trying.

Then, in your menu, you would instantiate the first view controller from each of your storyboards when the relevant button is clicked and push the new view controller on to your navigation stack, or, simply display the view controller modally, depending on what you want.

I believe the above should work but, as I mentioned before, I have not tested this myself. If you do run into issues, do ping me here and I'd be happy to help.