# Instagram redirect url issue in swift

Tags: ios, swift, instagram-api

I am implementing instagram login to my iOS app. I am logged in successfully but then I am not able to came to my app can any one tell me which is the valid redirect url for instagram? This is my code:

**Code**

```
  func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType: UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool {
        do {
            if let url = request.url {

                print(url)

                if String(describing: url).range(of: "#access_token") != nil {

                    try InstagramEngine.shared().receivedValidAccessToken(from: url)

                    if let accessToken = InstagramEngine.shared().accessToken {
                        print("accessToken: \(accessToken)")
                        //start

                        let URl =  "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/?access_token=\(accessToken)"

                        let parameter = [ "access_token" : accessToken ]

                        //    let URl = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/"

                      //  appInstance.showLoader()
                        Alamofire.request(URl, method: .get, parameters: parameter, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: nil)
                            .responseJSON { response in
                                //appInstance.hideLoader()
                                print(response.result.value!)

                                if response.result.isSuccess {

                                    let dict = response.result.value!

                                    do {

                                        var result : [String : AnyObject] = [String : AnyObject]()

                                        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dict, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)

                                        if let json = NSString(data: data, encoding:  String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue){

                                            print(json)
                                            result["result"] = json

                                            if hhSocialDelegate != nil{

                                                hhSocialDelegate.getInstagramLoginResponse(userData : result)
                                                _ =   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)

                                            }
                                        }

                                    }catch let err as NSError{
                                        print(err.debugDescription)
                                        _ =   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch let err as NSError {
            print(err.debugDescription)
            _ =   self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        }
        return true
    }
```

Here is my code for calling instagram api so please help me to solve that how can I come back to my app after login.

Comment: If you'd like a tip to avoid building a second set of Gaza pyramids, look at this section of a style guide: https://github.com/linkedin/swift-style-guide#311-using-guard-statements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to mention URI scheme you want to use in your app's Info.plist. Once that is done you can use URI scheme like com.myappid.name:/myCallback

[Info.plist-> Setting URI Scheme](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWu7t.png)

Comment: means which app id instagram developers app or any other?

Comment: You can use your app id (your bundle identifier) only.

Comment: com.Hemsandhub.InstagramDemo:/https://hemsandhub.auth0.com/login/callback like this way??

Comment: still i am redirectig to that url i am not able to came back in my app

Comment: can you please tell me format of redirect uri for insta gram for ios

Comment: You can use whatever you want as your redirect URI. You have to pass the redirect URI as a Get-parameter in your authorize request.https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=YOURCLIENTID&redirect_uri=YOURREDIRECTURI&response_type=code

Comment: yes thanks for helping me and can you please tell me how to logout from instagram after login

Comment: You need to remove all tokens and you probably have to clear browser history too.

Comment: this does not work with instagram

Answer (score 0):

Try this. For example you want to open an Instagram app:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33932755/4476989
or also read this one https://github.com/shyambhat/InstagramKit/issues/237

```
 var instagramHooks = "instagram://user?username=johndoe"
    var instagramUrl = NSURL(string: instagramHooks)
    if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(instagramUrl!)
    {  
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(instagramUrl!)

     } else {
        //redirect to safari because the user doesn't have Instagram
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://instagram.com/")!)
    }
```