# How can I call Waze App from codename in IOS devices

Tags: codenameone

I wrote a CodeNameOne Mobile App that launches "Waze App" and starts a visual navigation that helps our users (health professionals) reach at houses of their respective patients.

This App works fine in Android devices. 
I simply call "Display.getInstance().execute(url)" method and all done. (Great!!!).

But , in iOS devices, this feature doesn't work. 
I expected the same code should work on all platforms.

For iOS devices do I need to do some specific code or configuration?

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: [Possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443346/can-an-ipad-app-directly-launch-another-app); useful links on this question.

Comment: This seems duplicated, but it isn't. The key point of the question is how to call other apps (in this case Waze) using "CodeNameOne" approach and not native approach. It is one of  main reason I'm using CodeNameOne Framework. The abstraction of proprietary technology details. In this case the code works in Android and doesn't work in iOS. I would like to know why.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying this URL:

```
waze://?q=123%20main%20st%20San%20Jose%20California
```

Found it on the [Waze developer website](https://www.waze.com/about/dev).

[Display.execute](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#execute-java.lang.String-) should work if you want to explicitly invoke Waze but you should probably use `canExecute` to make sure it's available (notice that `canExecute` returns `Boolean` and **NOT** `boolean` as it has 3 modes).

Assuming you just want to navigate somewhere you can just call [openNativeNavigationApp](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Display.html#openNativeNavigationApp-double-double-).

Comment: I edited the answer to include some additional Codename One specific details.

Comment: Hi Shai. I'm using the correct URL, like this one you suggested in your comments. The URL format I'm using is based on Waze's API [Waze API Documentation](https://www.waze.com/about/dev).The URL Format is the same for Android and iOS.
The same java code (codenameone) works fine in android devices.
My App calls Waze and starts navigation immediately. The users liked a lot of that feature. But, at moment, only the android users are satisfied. 

Maybe I need to add one "Build Hint" like I did for access GPS in iOS devices.
Is there some "Codename Builder Hint" for that?

Comment: Your addtional infomation offered me a interesting workarround. It is close to my goal but it isn't exactly what I wanted. Because Waze has a lot of good features that makes it preferable solution and  makes our costumers more satisfied. I implemented you suggestion and it is now in production.I believe a more accurate solution can be obtained by writing native code for iOS and fortunately codenameone gives us this option. I'll try as soon as possible.